Correcting Existing Waste Water Drain Setup
Relevant background info: 200 year old stone farmhouse in PA. Built into a hillside so the first floor is also the basement.  At the rear of the house, the second floor is ground level.  The main soil pipe exits the center rear of the house between the second floor joists.  Adjacent to that is a 1.5” copper drain line that also exits the house and I assume joins the main pipe in the ground beneath the concrete pad behind the house.  There is a 1.5” vent coming vertically through the concrete pad.  The kitchen (and therefore the sink drain) is on the first floor.  The single bathroom is on the second floor directly above the spot that the waste lines exit the house.  That’s the entirety of the waste plumbing in the old part of the house (toilet, bathroom sink, tub, and kitchen sink).  This was all plumbed and replumbed by homeowners from the ‘70s to ‘90s.
Now to the issues we’ve had since moving in: because the kitchen sink is below the level at which the 1.5” copper line leaves the house, there is a pump under the kitchen sink… every time the pump runs it sends the wastewater into the bath tub and bathroom sink. I’d like to put a one way valve in to eliminate that.  The second issue is that the tub drain has been slowly clogging worse and worse for years and I can’t get a snake to make the 90° turns.  And there was zero access to the trap. Hence, I finally gave in and pulled the drywall down from the ceiling that was hiding the drain piping to address these issues.
I’m no plumbing expert but I’d guess there are a hundred things wrong here.  For one, I see they used sanitary tees in the horizontal orientation.  Suggestions on how best repipe this, at least for the short term?  Long term, the bathroom is being relocated and all this ripped out.



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It looks like the transition from plastic to copper (the rubber coupling) is misaligned, with the plastic pipe being below the copper pipe. Plastic pipe has a larger outside diameter than copper pipe of the same nominal dimension, it is expected to not match up evenly. However, this results in water remaining in the bottom of the plastic pipe and over time will leave a residue buildup in the pipe. Additionally, the pumped kitchen sink line is discharging right at this misalignment, which will impact the flow, resulting in back pressure (water flowing back up the drain towards the tub).
I would remove more of the copper line and replace it with plastic, moving the transition downstream of the kitchen sink connection as far as possible. When making the transition, try to keep the bottom of the two pipes aligned and as smooth as possible. This will allow the pipe to drain completely as well as provide more room for the pumped line to transition to gravity with less back pressure (or at least more room to account for the back pressure before the bathroom sink and tub).
The tees should be replaced with wyes and the 90° elbows for the bathroom sink should be replaced with two 45° elbows:

